# Neural network octave implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

Can anyone explain me this:

```
Theta1_grad(:, 1) = Theta1_grad(:, 1) ./ m;

Theta1_grad(:, 2:end) = Theta1_grad(:, 2:end) ./ m + ((lambda/m) * Theta1(:, 2:end));
```

I'm implementing in python, and I don't know Octave, I just found this neural network implementation, but I don't understand what is this doing.

Reference: http://feature-space.com/en/document49.pdf - 
Page 12 (2.5)

### EDIT:

Never mind, I think its trying to not to modify 1st column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Theta1_grad(:, 1)` gets the first column of the matrix `Theta1_grad` then it divides *each element* of this vector by the value of `m`

`Theta1_grad(:, 2:end)` gets the rest of the matrix starting from column 2 to the end (basically all the columns except the first column)

Typically the first column is set to `1` to allow for estimating the model intercept

In general, having `.` before the arithmetic operation in Octave means element by element operation, for example, `A * B` is normal matrix multiplication, but `A .* B` is element by element multiplication

Reading [a quick Octave](http://folk.ntnu.no/joern/itgk/refcard-a4.pdf), would help you.

**Edit:**

This equation is for a regularized neural network (to reduce over-fitting risk)

```
 Theta1_grad(:, 2:end) = Theta1_grad(:, 2:end) ./ m + ((lambda/m) * Theta1(:, 2:end));
```

I do not see the entire code but I believe lambda is *not* the learning rate, it is the regularization parameter (or the penalty) and it is multiplied by `Theta1` itself *not* the gradient.

Comment: just confuse with this- Theta1_grad(:, 2:end) = Theta1_grad(:, 2:end) ./ m + ((lambda/m) * Theta1(:, 2:end)); why its dividing by m and then adding same thing with multiplying learning rate, I don't understand

Comment: See my updated answer, basically it is not adding the same thing the first is the **gradient** and the second is **theta** itself

Comment: right, lamda is learning rate, Theta1 is weight vector. Now somewhat everything make sense ... possibly this's what I need - theta1_grad to update my weight vector - theta1.